# Passing array to function parameter in OpenCL

Tags: arrays, opencl

How do I pass array into a function in OpenCL? I got error "..argument of type "_global float *" is incompatible with parameter of type "float *" in line *c[n]=FindIndexFromArray(a,3)*;

```
float FindIndexFromArray(float myArray[], float Key)
{
    // simple looping to find the index
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(myArray);i++)
       if (myArray[i]==Key)
         return i; 

}

kernel void ProcessArray(
    global read_only float* myArray,
    global read_only float* Key,
    global write_only float* c )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0); 
    c[index] = FindIndexFromArray(myArray, Key); // How do I pass myArray parameter?
}
```

My edited source code:

```
float FindIndexFromArray(__global read_only float* myArray[], __global read_only float* Key)
{
    // simple looping to find the index
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(myArray);i++)
       if (myArray[i]==Key)
         return i; 

}

kernel void ProcessArray(
    __global read_only float* myArray,
    __global read_only float* Key,
    __global write_only float* c )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    c[index] = FindIndexFromArray(myArray, Key); // How do I pass myArray parameter?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as stated in the error message. your `myArray` and `Key` comes with the type `global` and `read-only`, thus you have to declare the same type when passing it to another function. In short your `FindIndexFromArray` should be

```
FindIndexFromArray(global read_only float* myArray, global read_only float* Key)
```

Comment: I still get several warning but this is the error message: `Operand types are incompatible ("float" and "__global float*"` in this line `if (myArray[i]==Key)`. I thought I have declared myArray and Key as __global type. How do I fix this?

Comment: eliminate `[]` in myArray, since it changes the type. regarding the sizeof(myArray), that wont give you the size of myArray you malloc'd. Instead pass the malloc size to your kernel, and then to your device function.

Comment: Sorry I forget to remove `[]`, the edited source code now produces error message as I stated in my first comment.

Comment: Okay.. your code is too messed up here.. First, if you want your function to return `int`, then change from from `float` to `int`. Second, you have to do something with `sizeof(myArray)` like I said. Third, the line `(myArray[i]==Key)` cannot be done because you're comparing a float value to a pointer to float. It should be `(myArray[i]==Key[i])` or `(myArray[i]==*Key)`..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12589/discussion-between-ina-ira-and-ardiyu07)